# How do I investigate a Checkbox disk/detect error?

Tags: checkbox

I assembled a computer and it lags a lot (especially when a browser is open).

As recommended on a different post, I ran a full Checkbox test to see what the problem is. It repeatedly returned a "disk/detect" error. Edit: it literally says nothing else on the issue. I've gone into the saved logs as well. For this test it says nothing else.

I read that that test was based on the lshw command. When I run that command, it seems to run without any problems.

How do I fix this error? Is it likely to be the cause of the laggy performance?

Edits:

I checked out the BIOS. All pieces of hardware appear to be correctly recognised.

**Main Specs**

CPU: Threadripper 1950X

RAM: 32 GB

Motherboard: Asrock X399 Taichi

GPU: GTX 1080 Ti

Drive: Samsung 960 NVMe. I bought it new and unused.

Software: Ubuntu 16.04

Power: 1500W - which according to pcpartpicker is a huge surplus (I designed it for multi-GPU but only have one for now).

Comment: Please edit your question to add the complete relevant checkbox output. Many "disk/detect" errors are due to faulty hardware, faulty connecting cable, or a poorly-seated connecting cable (none of those are Ubuntu-related problems). Yes, disk failure may lead to poor performance.

Comment: "I assembled a computer" gives insufficient information to begin to troubleshoot. First items needed what is the processor, how much memory, and how old the HDD? Next does the BIOS recognise the various components correctly.
Before installing any software did the computer boot? I recommend going back to the start, first be sure all hardware is rocognised correctly using the BIOS, if all hardware is then, re-install software.

Answer (score 0):

I would test first by running Ubuntu off a Live USB disk or switching out the HDD if that is possible.

That would tell you a lot. If it is the HDD, well, just reinstall Ubuntu, if not, my guess would be a power supply mismatch?

Comment: Thanks. I ran it off of a USB. It didn't lag. You said I should just reinstall Ubuntu, but if it's a problem with the HDD (i.e. the hardware itself) why will reinstalling Ubuntu help?